# Birthday Paradox Variant: Probability of getting X days with only one birthday

Tags: probability, combinatorics, birthday

I don't know whether this question has been asked or not, or if it's on the Wikipedia, and apologies if so but I wanted to know:

> Given a group of *n* people, what is the probability of X people having a unique birthday, i.e. Any particular person (in this group of X people) will not have the same birthday as anyone else.

This goes with the assumptions that birthdays are uniformly distributed. I am looking for an analytical solution, a theorem or wiki that would help and even just a gauge on how hard a problem like this is would be a lot of help.

To clarify, I am looking for something along the lines of Pr(X) = f(n), where f is a function of n.

Thanks

Comment: An easier question is the expected number of people with a unique birthday, which is $n \left(1-\frac{1}{365}\right)^{n-1}$

Comment: For what its worth, someone else [asked the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4854537/dice-probabilities-and-stars-bars) formulated differently with dice.  I have not thought of a good solution yet beyond brute force or simulation.  There are certain special cases that can be covered with https://oeis.org/A231797 and binomial coefficients if number of "days" and number of "people" are the same, but the more general case does seem difficult even now to me.

Comment: As alluded to in the oeis link, generating functions can work wonders, but actually utilizing them effectively for something like this which does not appear to simplify is admittedly not much different than brute force.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Don't underestimate the power of inclusion–exclusion :-) I answered the other question you linked to and am closing this one as a duplicate.

Comment: @JMoravitz Brute force could involve processing something like $365^n$ possibilities. I suspect recursion could easily reduce this to $366^2(n+1)$ or less (e.g. number of unique birthdays, number of shared birthdays, number of people so far) which would not be as difficult

Comment: Thanks for the help JMoravitz and @joriki. I was reading the proof you gave [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4854537/dice-probabilities-and-stars-bars), and got stuck on this formula

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-i}(-1)^j\binom{n-i}{j}j!\binom{k-i}{j}(k-i-j)^{n-i-j}$$

I was wondering why we sum from 0 to n-i. I would have thought that the for j=0, this includes the union of all having 0 to n-i conditions violated, then subtracting j=1 would subtract the union of having 1 to n-i condition violated, giving the combinations of 0 conditions violated.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out by looking at the Wikipedia